# Terminology: measures that are absolutely continuous wrt each other

Tags: measure-theory

One says that measure $\nu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t $\mu$, $\nu \ll \mu$, if every $\mu$-negligible set is also $\nu$-negligible. Is there any standard name for the equivalence relation defined by

$$\nu \equiv \mu \iff \nu\ll\mu \mbox{ and } \mu\ll\nu? $$

And is there a standard terminology for the equivalence classes thus defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply called *equivalence* in measure theory, as far as I know. See for instance this article on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_(measure_theory)) which references Klenke's *Probability Theory*.